# Reflecting assemblies in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, iis-7

I have an application in which I am using reflection to call methods that in are different classes generated through using NetTiers.

In order to do that, I'm loading the NetTiers services assembly by getting the Executing Assembly using:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

and loading the class by:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(<Assembly Path using above>.dll).GetType(<className>)
```

This seems to work some of the time, however sometimes, loading the assembly fails with the following exception:

> Error Loading assembly from Execution :C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\21d6c367\aa208bcd\assembly\dl3\e825b934\00f26fab_a39ecc01\.dll class:

and Stack Trace:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\21d6c367\aa208bcd\assembly\dl3\e825b934\00f26fab_a39ecc01\.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\21d6c367\aa208bcd\assembly\dl3\e825b934\00f26fab_a39ecc01\.dll'
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.  To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Is there a better way to load classes from assemblies, or am I missing something that results in this error occuring for some classes, but not for others? I am running the application using IIS7.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName())
```

To load the assembly.

However I believe that `GetExecutingAssembly` is not necessarily reliable due to JIT inlining etc; for the same reasons as `GetCallingAssembly`.  `GetEntryAssembly`is probably better - but in a web application it's likely to be another dynamically generated assembly thanks to Global.asax - i.e. it won't necessarily contain any of your code directly.

Really it would be a lot better if you knew in advance at least the name of the assembly - and then you can use the `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)` method like above, without having to worry about the filename (loading by filename is not always a good idea - you can get duplicate assemblies in memory if you load from a place that's different to where the runtime would've loaded.

Answer (score 0):

from the path given you can see that you haven't specified a name for the dll see `\.dll`

Comment: I am specifing the .dll in the path to the assembly.

Comment: @Steve - could be that the call is originating from some dynamic code via the 'Anonymously hosted' assembly. Or at least that the actual call has been inlined into that.  However, if the Class Name is assembly qualified, then you don't need to load the assembly first.  If not, then this pattern is unreliable and you need a safer way to know the assembly in advance.  `GetEntryAssembly()` would be more reliable, but not necessarily right.